# How to list all running X applications?

Tags: linux, xorg, solaris, ps, screenshot

I'd like to get a list of all of the apps (across all users) on my machine that are talking to the X server. What's the most reliable way to do that? Find the socket X runs on and lsof for connections to it? I'm running both Linux and Solaris boxes, so I'd be interested in answers for both OS's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.xfree86.org/current/xlsclients.1.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about Solaris:

[`xrestop`](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xrestop) might be helpful.

Comment: `xlsclients` is just the same on Solaris as it is on Linux and all other Unix-like systems.